# Manipulating the number of neurons in the hidden layer in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, weka

I'm classifying datasets in Weka with a MLP. My question is how can I change the number of hidden neurons in the hidden layer? Only the option about number of hidden layers is available.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Your question seems to be quite specific to Weka. Note that this site is intended to be a resource for statistical questions that are *agnostic* wrt software. If you're lucky, there will be some Weka experts who can help you, but don't assume that one will be forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Weka for some time now and I'm not sure you can do that, it allows you to change the number of hidden layers and so on. If you are using the Weka interface you could try the SPM Simulator developed in the UC3M, it is focused on MLP and it gives you more posibilities (such as number of neurons in hidden layer) It is in spanish though.